Nuxt Js 3 Build Stucked at this line Σ Total size: 4.94 MB (1.23 MB gzip)?
This is my nuxt.config.ts when i am using hook of "prerender:routes" my build is getting stucked both locally and on any hosting platform Build Stucked Image
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt/config';


export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: '2024-04-03',
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  plugins: ['~/plugins/vuetify.js'],
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify'],
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      dbUrl: process.env.DB_URL,
    }
  },
  css: [
    'vuetify/styles',
    '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css',
  ],
  ssr: false,
  nitro: {
    routeRules: {
      '/': { isr: true },
      '/contact': { ssr: false },
      '/projects': { isr: true }, 

    },
    preset:'netlify',
  },


  hooks: {
      
     async "prerender:routes" (ctx){
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://nuxt-project-sandy.vercel.app/api/getAllProjects');
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
  
        const projects = await response.json();
        projects.forEach((project: { _id: string }) => {
          ctx.routes.add(`/project/${project._id}`);
        });
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching projects:', error);
      }
     }
  },
});




I am removing the hooks and hardcoding a single route
routeRules: {
      '/': { isr: true },
      '/contact': { ssr: false },
      '/projects': { isr: true },
'/project/66e0120073ecac4add9472bc':{prerender:true} 

    },

and even after  using this my build is  still getting stucked at the particular line.

Issue is probably coming from a specific build step. Not sure if you can have some verbose output or a way to comment-out piece of your code to narrow down the issue.
